# Error when i test tf.tensor.as4D();

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Can someone explain to me why I have this error and what should I do when I work with 4D tensors.

> I try this code and always fail on 4D tensor

Thank you all.

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const x = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

const row = 5;
const column = 5;
const depth = 1;
const depth2 = 1;

// Convert from 1D to 2D tensor.
x.as2D(row, column).print();

// Convert from 1D to 3D tensor
x.as3D(row, column, depth).print();

// Convert from 1D to 4D tensor
x.as4D(row, column, depth, depth2).print();
```

#### Error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Size (6) must match the product of shape 5,5
>   Error: Size (6) must match the product of shape 5,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error text, the incoming tensor `x` has 6 elements, not 25 as would be indicated by the shape ( 5, 5, 1, 1 ), so the error has nothing to do with the conversion per se but with the fact that you don't have enough elements to fill 25 boxes. :)

Comment: Thank so much @peter I am new and I was confused with tensors greater than 3D.

Comment: Well now you have 10 elements, make `const column = 2;` and that should do it... No matter how many dims, the number of elements is always the _product_ of all the dim sizes.